# How to apply in validator different behaviours for particular methods in spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, validation, model-view-controller

I would like to get answer if this approach for validation if there is possibility to customise validator for different controller methods.

Simple validator

```
@Component
public class UserDtoValidator implements Validator {
@Autowired
UserService userService;

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
    return UserDto.class.isAssignableFrom(aClass);
}

@Override
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
    UserDto userDto = (UserDto) target;

    }
   //how to make 'if' below to be applied only for certain method in controller
   //in this case for controller createUser method
    if (userService.findByUserName(userDto.getUserName())!=null) {
        throw new InvalidPayloadException("Creating user requires unique userName");
    }
   //second 'if' for controller updateUser method 
     if (userService.findByUserName(userDto.getUserName())==null) {
        throw new InvalidPayloadException("Updating unexisting users is not allowed");
    }
  }
}
```

Controller:

Here we have two opposite situations for validator:

1 Creating user with unique userName

2 Updating user - required userName

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/users")
public class ApiUserController extends ExceptionsResolver {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private UserDtoValidator userDtoValidator;
    @InitBinder
    private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(userDtoValidator);
    }


    @RequestMapping(consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity createUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserDto userDto) throws JsonProcessingException {
        userService.saveUser(userDto);
        return new ResponseEntity(userDto, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{userName}", consumes = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<UserDto> updateUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserDto userDto, @PathVariable String userName) {
         return new ResponseEntity("User updated", HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
     }

}
```

BTW I know that PUT should create new, but here I need just PUT for updating purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of a way to know from within the validator whether you're creating or updating a user (using an Interceptor and a ThreadLocal object) but not of an elegant one.

I know that it's not exactly what you've asked for, but I think what I would do is use a custom validation annotation that looks something like:

```
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = UsernameValidator.class)
public @interface Username
{
    String message() default "...";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    boolean isUpdate() default true;
}
```

And the validator:

```
public class UsernameValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Username, String>
{
    private boolean isUpdate;

    public void initialize(Username constraintAnnotation)
    {
        isUpdate = constraintAnnotation.isUpdate();
    }

    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context)
    {
        if (isUpdate)
        {
            // Make sure the user exists
        }
        else
        {
            // Make sure the user doesn't exist
        }           
    }
}
```

A usage of such implementation would simply look like:

```
@Username                           // In case of an update
@Username(isUpdate = false)         // In case of a creation
```

You'll have to convert it to your specific use case of course, but I believe you get the point.

Hope I still managed to somehow help you. Good luck!

Comment: Giving you a vote for the right idea, and hopefully my answer helps him bind it all together.

Comment: @Adi It is possible to somehow set \@Username(isUpdate = false) in controller - I tried "public ResponseEntity createUser( \@Valid \@UserNameUnique(isUpdate = false) \@RequestBody UserDto userDto)..." but it doesn't work.

Comment: @abrasadera, you should definitely be able to us it in Spring's controllers. Does your controller's class have the `@Validated` annotation?

Comment: Yep I've added this annotation but still didn't managed to make it work - I'll try to fix it or start new SO question - thanx :)

Answer (score 5):

What you really care about is whether the username exists. In some cases you want it to, in some cases you don't.

In theory you could use a `@Username` annotation with an `exists` attribute. That's similar to Adi's `isUpdate`, but don't call it `isUpdate`. You don't care about the operation requiring the validation, you just care if the username exists or not.

Validation groups are designed for this problem, i.e. to validate a bean differently in different situations. Create two validation groups `NewUser` and `ExistingUser`. Replace the `@Valid` calls in your `@Controller` with Spring's `@Validated`.

```
public ResponseEntity createUser(@Validated(NewUser.class) @RequestBody UserDto userDto) throws JsonProcessingException {}

public ResponseEntity<UserDto> updateUser(@Validated(ExistingUser.class) @RequestBody UserDto userDto, @PathVariable String userName) {}
```

In the `UserDto` class, in theory you'd mark the `username` property as

```
@Username(exists = true, groups = ExistingUser.class);
@Username(exists = false, groups = NewUser.class);
public String getUsername() {}
```

But Java won't let you do that. So then you need a workaround to set multiple username constraints. This is used all over the place in the Bean Validation API, e.g. in `NotNull`

```
/**
 * Defines several <code>@NotNull</code> annotations on the same element
 * @see javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
 *
 * @author Emmanuel Bernard
 */
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@interface List {
    NotNull[] value();
}
```

With this stuff in place, you just need a `UsernameValidator` that can check whether the username exists or not based on the `exists` flag, and the validation groups will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it seems there is no 'magical' solution to this thing.

I ended up with validator with common stuff for update and save. Specific checks were left in controller methods.

One another solution is to create a separate dto(if you not using dto objects for orm purposes). And use JSR-303 validation annotations on them(for brevity). But this solution is really depends on specific case. For example it seems suitable if only small subset of fields could be updated.